# sql rank diplay requested rank number

Tags: sql, rank

Query:

```
SELECT distinct 
rank() OVER (ORDER BY p.service) as rank,
p.service, 
From table_service
Where 1=1
```

Output:
Rank:1 | Service: test1
Rank:2 | Service: test2
Rank:3 | Service: test3

how i can display only Rank 2 ?

i tried this but is not working:

```
SELECT distinct 
rank() OVER (ORDER BY p.service) as rank,
p.service, 
From table_service
Where rank = 2
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a subquery, because `where` can't use an alias name to do condition.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        rank() OVER (ORDER BY p.service) as rank,
        p.service, 
    From table_service
) t1
where rank = 2
```

Comment: you are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

Put your query into a subquery:

```
select *
from
(
SELECT distinct 
rank() OVER (ORDER BY p.service) as rank,
p.service, 
From table_service
) sub
Where rank = 2;
```

Comment: you are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

Why use rank?  Most databases support `offset/fetch` or something similar:

```
select p.service,
from table_service p
order by p.service
offset 1 fetch first 1 row only;
```